# How CPU predicts, the instruction and data limits in the sequence of binary information of binary file?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, machine-code, instruction-set, illegal-instruction

How CPU Differentiate the instruction from the data?

How CPUs determines the length of instruction(it varies from 1 byte upto 15 byte max) while executing the code? if suppose the cpu does not determine the length of instruction, it may  take the data as a part of instruction. In that case ,  undesired result may come or cpu doesn't execute that instruction(if not in opcode sheet).  How cpu determines, whether it is data or instruction?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to predict.  **Logically it decodes one byte at a time until it sees a complete instruction.**  (or dword chunks for disp32 or imm32, or other multi-byte parts of an instruction implied by an earlier byte.)  The length of the instruction is implied by prefixes and the opcode + modrm + SIB bytes.  After looking at those, the CPU knows for sure how many more instruction bytes it needs to fetch.

But a real CPU only has to give the illusion of doing that, and **can look at later bytes as long as it eventually does the right thing if they turn out not to be part of an instruction that should execute.**

Physically in a real implementation, there's no problem speculatively loading later bytes as long as you eventually do the right thing.

e.g. L1 instruction cache uses 64-byte lines, so logical execution reaching a byte means the whole 64-byte chunk of memory will be in the I-cache, even if it's *also* in the L1 D-cache because you did some data load instructions on other bytes in that same line.

And fetch from L1I cache isn't single bytes at a time either, of course.  On modern x86, decode looks at blocks of 32 or 16 bytes to find instruction boundaries.  e.g. lets look at P6-family, which doesn't have a uop cache so it does always fetch/decode from L1I.

From [Agner Fog's microarch PDF](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf), in the PPro/PII/PIII section:

> **6.2 Instruction fetch**
>
> **Instruction codes are fetched from the code cache in aligned 16-byte chunks** into a double
> buffer that can hold two 16-byte chunks. The purpose of the double buffer is to make it
> possible to decode an instruction that crosses a 16-byte boundary (i.e. an address divisible
> by 16). The code is passed on from the double buffer to the decoders in blocks which I will
> call IFETCH blocks (instruction fetch blocks).  The IFETCH blocks are up to 16 bytes long. In
> most cases, the instruction fetch unit makes each IFETCH block start at an instruction
> boundary rather than a 16-byte boundary. However, the instruction fetch unit needs
> information from the instruction length decoder in order to know where the instruction
> boundaries are. If this information is not available in time then it may start an IFETCH block
> at a 16-byte boundary. This complication will be discussed in more detail below.

The pre-decoder pipeline stage then finds instruction boundaries (assuming they're all valid instructions), then (following the predictions made by the branch-prediction unit) the machine code for 3 instructions is sent to the 3 decoders in parallel.  (Core2 widened to 4 decoders, Skylake widened to 5 decoders even though the pipeline width stays at 4 uops wide).

**If there's an illegal instruction in there somewhere (or an unconditional `jmp`, or a `jcc` that happens to be taken), then later "instructions" are meaningless and get discarded upon discovery of that fact.**

https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/5/ talks about the decode stages in Nehalem, the last generation of P6-family microarchitectures.  But Agner Fog's description is probably more useful in terms of understanding how **the CPU can look at a bunch of bytes, and then end up only using the ones that should logically be executed as instructions**.